# Checking of a line is in a file with bufferedread and hashset

Tags: java, hashset, bufferedreader, filewriter

My problem is that I have to write code to check if a customers name is already in my txt file (Customers.txt).

The problem is that I check with hashset if the customer is in the file and he says that he isn't in the file while he is.(Checked it manually)
Please help me solve this.

The code that I already have is below.

```
    public class Customer {
    //declaration
    public static String S;
    private String line ;
    public String nameCustomer;


/**
 * constructor
 */
public Klant(){}

/**Checking of the customer is in the file
 */
public void getCustomer() {
    // make SimpleInOutDialog      
        SimpleInOutDialog  input = new SimpleInOutDialog("Customers");
        nameCustomer = input.readString("Give in the name");
    try{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("L:\\Documents/Informatica/6de jaar/GIP/Customers.txt"));
    HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
    int i = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        i++;
        if (i == 1){hs.add(br.readLine());}

        if (i % 4 == 0){hs.add(br.readLine());}

    }
    if(hs.contains(nameCustomer)){
        //the customer exists
     input.showString("The customer exists", "");
     }else{input.showString("The customer does not exist, we will make a new one", "");
         setNieuweKlant();}


    }catch (Exception e){//Catch when there are errors
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());}

}


/**
 * make a new customer
 */

public void Make new customer(){
    // make SimpleInOutDialog     
    SimpleInOutDialog  input = new SimpleInOutDialog("A new customer");
    //input
    S = "Name customer: " + input.readString("Give in your name:");
WriteToFile();
S = "Adress: " + input.readString("Give your adress");
WriteToFile();
S = "Telephonenummber: " + input.readString("Give your telephonenumber");
WriteToFile();
//making a customerID
  UUID idCustomer = UUID.randomUUID();  
S = "CustomerID: " + customerID.toString();
WriteToFile();

}


/**
 * Schrijft de gegevens weg naar het bestand
 */


 public void WriteToFile(){
try{

FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("L:\\Documents/Informatica/6de jaar/GIP/Customer.txt", true);
BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
//Wrting away your data
out.write(S);

//Closing the writer
out.close();


}catch (Exception e){//Catch when there are errors
    System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());
    }
    }
```

**Dutcht Code**

```
public class Klant {
    //declaratie van de variabele die de tekst voorsteld
    public static String S;
    private String line ;
    public String naamklant;


/**
 * constructor
 */
public Klant(){}

/**Controleerd of de klant al bestaat
 */
public void getKlant() {
    // SimpleInOutDialog aanmaken     
        SimpleInOutDialog  input = new SimpleInOutDialog("Klanten");
        naamklant = input.readString("Geef de volledige naam in");
    try{
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("L:\\Documents/Informatica/6de jaar/GIP/Klanten.txt"));
    HashSet<String> hs = new HashSet<String>();
    int i = 0;
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        i++;
        if (i == 1){hs.add(br.readLine());}

        if (i % 4 == 0){hs.add(br.readLine());}

    }
    if(hs.contains(naamklant)){
        //klant bestaat
     input.showString("De klant bestaat", "");
     }else{input.showString("De klant bestaat niet, er wordt een nieuwe klant aangemaakt", "");
         setNieuweKlant();}


    }catch (Exception e){//Catch wanneer er errors zijn
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());}

}


/**
 * Maakt een nieuwe klant aan 
 */

public void setNieuweKlant(){
    // SimpleInOutDialog aanmaken     
    SimpleInOutDialog  input = new SimpleInOutDialog("Een nieuwe klant");
    //input
    S = input.readString("Geef de volledige naam in");
    WriteToFile();
    S = "Adres: " + input.readString("Geef het adres op");
    WriteToFile();
    S = "Telefoonummer: " + input.readString("Geef het telefoonnummer op");
    WriteToFile();
    //een klantennummer aanmaken 
      UUID idKlant = UUID.randomUUID();  
    S = "Klantnummer: " + idKlant.toString();
    WriteToFile();

}


/**
 * Schrijft de gegevens weg naar het bestand
 */
public void WriteToFile(){

    try{

        FileWriter writer = new FileWriter("L:\\Documents/Informatica/6de jaar/GIP/Klanten.txt", true);
        BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(writer);
        //uw gegevens wegschrijven
        out.write(S);
        out.newLine();
        //de writer sluiten
        out.close();


    }catch (Exception e){//Catch wanneer er errors zijn
        System.err.println("Error: " + e.getMessage());}



    }


}
```

Comment: Your code would be a *lot* easier to read if you used more conventional naming (and gave meaningful names to your variables), and formatted it sensibly.

Comment: You should post your actual code. Dutch variable names aren't ideal, but they're better than broken code. (`Make new customer`, for example, is not a valid method-name in Java.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm really not sure what you're trying to do overall (reading every 4th line, etc.), but I wouldn't use a `HashSet` if all you want is to check if a string exists in a file.

Here's a complete program for checking if a string exists in a file:

```
import java.io.*;

public class CheckName
{
  private static boolean doesNameExistInFile(String name, String filename)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
  {
    BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(filename));

    String line = null;

    try {
      while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
        if (line.equals(name))
          return true;
      }

    } finally {
      // Always close() before exiting.
      reader.close();
    }

    return false;
  }

  public static void main(String[] args)
    throws FileNotFoundException, IOException
  {
    boolean exists = doesNameExistInFile("Bender", "input.txt");

    System.out.println(exists ? "Exists!" : "Does not exist.");
  }
}
```

Contents of input file `input.txt`:

```
Leela
Fry
Professor
Hermes
Zoidberg
```

A couple of things to note:

1. We don't read the entire file. We stop reading once we've found the string, as that's all we're interested in.
2. Always `close()` before exiting, whether string is found or not. We put the call in the `finally` block.

Comment: Oke thanks alot!! Now have to think how I will use this class in a methode , so I can call for it ...

Answer (score 1):

This:

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        i++;
        if (i == 1){hs.add(br.readLine());}

        if (i % 4 == 0){hs.add(br.readLine());}

    }
```

is probably supposed to be this:

```
    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
    {
        i++;
        if (i == 1)
            hs.add(line);
        if (i % 4 == 0)
            hs.add(line);
    }
```

That is — you probably meant to `add` the line that you had just read, rather than reading in a *new* line and `add`ing it.

Comment: Also, seems it reads line 1, 4, 8 etc., the first line is correct but the rest read the customer number. Both should probably be replaced by a `if(i%4==1)`.

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson So what needs to be changed in the code? or is the code you gave correct?

Comment: @NB. It should be, although you can always print out `line` in ruakh's code to see that you're getting the correct content to compare to.

Comment: @ruakh I changed the code like u said , but it still says that I need to make a new customer while my customer is in the file.. Is there another way than hashset to check if my customer is in the txt file?

Comment: @Joachim Isaksson and how do I need to get that in my code ? sorry still not great with java --'

Comment: @NB.: Change every occurrence of `hs.add(line);` to `{ hs.add(line); System.err.println("Adding '" + line + "' to hs."); }`, and then run the program. This will let you see what lines are actually being added to `hs`, so you can make sure they're the right ones.